# elisp equivalent of python shlex.split?

Tags: python, elisp, shlex

I need to parse a command line in elisp, something like:

```
(shlex-split "command \"Some file with spaces\" someother\ quote")
;;That gives ("command" "Some file with spaces" "someother quote")
```

How can I accomplish this in a simple way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(split-string-and-unquote "command \"Some file with spaces\" someother\ quote")